# how to check if two objects in the same position using rect.colliderect(rect2) after some time of game passes?

Tags: python, pygame, rect

Well, I need to make dog chasing the ball and the ball chasing the mouse cursor. When the dog in the same position as the ball, the game should stop and print "Game over". Now, my code checks if the two objects in the same position immediately after starting the game, so it ends, because at the start objects in the same position. How can I make it check positions after some time of game passes?

```
`
    if rect.colliderect(rect2) == True:
        clock.tick(1000)
        self.chasing = False
        rect3 = self.fontim.get_rect()
        rect3 = rect3.move((self.width-rect3.width)//2,
                          (self.height-rect3.height)//2)

    pygame.display.flip()

MyGame().run()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pygame.time.Clock`

Usage:

You first create a Clock. Then once every frame, you should call `Clock.tick()`, which will return the amount of milliseconds passed since the last call. This way you can increment a milliseconds_passed variable, and also check, when a certain amount of time has passed.

I recommend to make a subclass of Clock, and add a millisenonds_passed variable, which will avoid any clutter in your code.

EDIT:

There are a few mistakes in your code.

Firstly, `Clock.tick()` is not called once every frame. It is called once every frame when the dog collides with the ball. Move it preferably to your run method.

Secondly, you are not getting the return value of your clock. As I wrote, it returns the amount of milliseconds passed since the last call. So create a new variable, that will be increased by what that method returns. Lastly what you will need is a simple check, you could even do it in the same if statement. Like this:

```
if rect.colliderect(rect2) == True and self.time_passed/1000 > 5:
```

Comment: hmm it should help.. but do you know any examples of using it in code?

Comment: self.time_passed should be equal to how many times self.clock.tick() was called right? because it called every 30 frames, we have the amount of time passed? do I understand it right?

Comment: `self.time_passed += self.clock.tick()` since tick() returns the time elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Make a timer which is initialized when the game starts, and whenever a collision is encountered, check if time > 2 seconds for instance.

Comment: hmm it should help, can you tell me how to set timer? I looked at pygame documentation, but didn't really understand it

Comment: or start checking after a mouse click has been made

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski I think the idea with timer is what I need to do

Comment: @user2926550 you already are using a timer in your program, so what is the problem with using it again?